# How can i get java holder class value in jsp

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

i have set value inside my Contexte class.
Below is part of my jsp page code

```
<%@page language = "java"%>
<%@page session="true" import="collections.*"%>
<%
JspBeansCollection jspbeans = new JspBeansCollection((Contexte)request.getAttribute("ctx"));
session.putValue("jspbeans",jspbeans);
...
%>
```

Comment: Instead of using java code use EL, also putValue is deprecated for HTTPSession instead use setAttribute

Comment: what is EL, and i am using servlet.

Comment: EL is expression language which helps get rid of Java code in your view layer (JSP), it is related to JSP and has nothing to do with Servlet. You can read the official tutorial at http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnahq.html